# Account restrictions

Tags: security

I have tried this: `ALL=/usr/bin`, `!/usr/bin/passwd`, `!/usr/bin/su`, but not success.

Is it possible user with sudoers permission can't able to change any password except his own user account ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pete        ALL = ALL, !/usr/bin/passwd [A-Z][a-z]*,  /usr/bin/passwd pete
```

This should work. [Source](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/sudoers.html) is the sudoers manual.

Comment: Edited the initial answer. Essentially what this line means is `pete` can run any command, except `passwd <something>`, except `passwd pete`. 

Also, you might want to remove `pete`'s ability to create and delete users, else he can just delete user, create it again with some other password. I'm not sure if it's a possibility, but I sniff a chance. :D